# Read tag time on Android

Tags: android, tags, nfc

I am developing app with some NFC action. Now I am dealing with read tag time, from discovery, to complete data read. I thought it should be easy, so I did:

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(final Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        startReadTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // i am reading time if Tag is doscovered
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ReadContent(intent);
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

And reading Tag data

```
private void ReadContent(Intent intent) {
    NdefMessage[] messages = null;
    Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent
            .getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
    final long stopReadTime = System.currentTimeMillis();//I am reading time when read is stopped
//rest of the code
......
}
```

But time seems to not be reliable. I read 8K tag and with simple stopwatch I can see that it takes some 3 seconds, but measured time stamps gives me only 1-3 milliseconds.
I would like to measure time from Tag discovered sound on Android, to completing reading. 
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time that you get your `ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent, the tag has already been read.

The call to `intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES)`is more or less just a simple getter function that does very little.

There is no way for an application to measure the time from the tag detection sound to intent invocation.